# Sequelize bulkCreate behavior when failures occur

Tags: model, sequelize.js, bulk-create

What is the actual behavior of bulkCreate in case only one insert fails? The whole process is cancelled, or the remaining lines are inserted?
I read on some forums that the behavior would be equivalent to Promise.all() so that no lines are inserted on failure.
If this is true how can we change this to Promise.allsettled() returning successes and failures?
I found failure logs reporting database errors, such as connection errors, invalid data for a column, etc.

Ths

P.S: using mysql database